# Программа для печати штрихкодов на принтере Godex 530 на языке python

Tags: python, barcode

Есть программа на pythone по считыванию штрихкодов, сейчас возникла необходимость добавить в программу возможность печати шрихкода.
Принтер Godex 530 подключен через USB.
Собственно вопрос, с чего начать?

Comment: С поиска библиотек на питоне, что смогу с принтером работать

Answer (score 3):

Решил проблему тем, что все таки подключил принтере через ethernet, а дальше, на сайте зебры нашел пример того как отправить на принтер по сети zpl код для печати. Godex поддерживает ZPL.

```
import socket
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
host = "10.80.209.106" 
port = 9100   
try:           
   mysocket.connect((host, port)) #connecting to host
   mysocket.send(b"^XA^A0N,50,50^FO50,50^FDSocket Test^FS^XZ")#using bytes
   mysocket.close () #closing connection
except:
   print("Error with the connection")
```

Comment: escpos более распространен, но вариант тоже хорош, хоть и лоулевельный

Answer (score 2):

Этот принтер скорее всего поддерживает escpos.

https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/barcode.html

Если он определился как ком или лпт порт - то скорее всего он в нужном режиме. Если нет, то обоатитесь к мануалу принтера.

Также можно штрихкоды рисовать на картинке и отправлять картинку в очередь печати.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, проблему решил. Решение добавил к самому вопросу.

Comment: @PavelShiryaev, лучше оформите сами ответ, внизу страницы есть что-то вроде "Ответить на собственный вопрос"

Comment: @gil9red Понял, спасибо.